# No matching function for call to vector

Tags: c++

I get the error: [Error] no matching function for call to 'subjects::subjects(std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, int&, int&)'.
Here is my code:

```
void listInput(subjects a){
//  subjects a;
    cout<<"Enter the name of the subject"<<endl;
    cin>>a.subjectName;
    while(a.subjectName.empty()){
        cout<<"Error, subject name must not be empty"<<endl;
        cin>>a.subjectName;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the name of lecturer"<<endl;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, a.lectName);
    while(checkName(a.lectName)!=1){
        cout<<"Error, invalid input"<<endl;
        getline(cin, a.lectName);
    }
    cout<<"Enter the surname of lecturer"<<endl;
    getline(cin, a.lectSurname);
    while(checkName(a.lectSurname)!=1){
        cout<<"Error, invalid input"<<endl;
        getline(cin, a.lectSurname);
    }
    a.credits=a.enterNumber("Enter the number of credits\n");
    a.studentnum=a.enterNumber("Enter the number of students\n");
    a.entry.push_back(new subjects(a.subjectName, a.lectName,a.lectSurname,a.credits, a.studentnum));
}
```

And header file:

```
#ifndef SUBJECT
#define SUBJECT

#include <string>
#include <vector>


class subjects{
    private:
        std::string subjectName;
        std::string lectName;
        std::string lectSurname;
        int credits;
        int studentnum;

    public:
        subjects(){
            subjectName="";
            lectName="";
            lectSurname="";
            credits=0;
            studentnum=0;
        }
        int userChoice();
        int enterNumber(std::string name);
        void menu();
        friend void listInput(subjects a);
        bool checkName(std::string &text);
        std::vector<subjects*> entry;

};

#endif
```

How can i fix this? Or should i not use vector in this case, ignore the friend function, as we are required to use it

Comment: Well, you do not have a constructor that takes parameters - so how do you expect `new subjects(a.subjectName, a.lectName,a.lectSurname,a.credits, a.studentnum)` to work?

Comment: `subjects::subjects` doesn't accept arguments, according to the header

Comment: Your question title has nothing to do with the content.

Comment: First, reduce your code to an MCVE. Not only is this required to make you question on topic, it also helps you to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a constructor that takes all those arguments.  Add another constructor to `subjects` that takes the appropriate parameters and your code should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a default constructor, but no constructor taking four parameters. You can have both at the same time by adding a constructor with defaults:

```
subjects(
    const std::string subjectName=""
,   const std::string lectName = ""
,   const std::string lectSurname=""
,   const int credits = 0
,   const int studentnum = 0
) : subjectName(subjectName)
,   lectName(lectName)
,   lectSurname(lectSurname)
,   credits(credits)
,   studentnum(studentnum)
{
}
```

This approach lets you call `subjects` constructor with zero, one, two, three, four, or five parameters. When the number of passed parameters is fewer than five, the defaults are used for the remaining ones.